# How can I send data to a specific port and ip? as its continously changing its ip and port

Tags: node.js

How can I send data to a specific port and IP, As I am developing a server for GPS vehicle tracking, I am continuously receiving data from **new** IP: Port with every connection drop, its change IP, and port to establish a new connection.

My problem is, I want to send some data to the device but its continuously changing IP and port, so anyone please tell me how to tackle with IP and port changing issue and how I can send data to its IP and port

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the network (as in how the GPS connects to the network) you could try set up a dynamic DNS service such as: [noip](https://www.noip.com/free) or [changeip](https://www.changeip.com/dns.php)

I don't know your exact configuration, but for example, I used to run noip on a Raspberry Pi which was running as a web server. I didn't have a static IP address provided from my service provider so using noip to map a domain name they provide to what ever my IP was at the time resolved this issue.

If it's of any help, you could look at a tutorial like this to see how it works: https://cookuop.co.uk/install-noip-on-raspberry-pi/

Not quite sure how this would work with your changing port though.

Comment: Hello  can you please contact me on 
"chaitanya@nextechinfoway.com" as I have some technical work regard node.js
 
I am stuck at as connection data from IP/port changed on every new connection.when there is a connection between server and device I want to inject data from the server to device (same IP/ port from which I am receiving data).